# Path application Postgresql installation on Windows 64 bit

Tags: postgresql

I want to know where is postgresql installation path on Windows XP 64 bit.

If on Windows 32 bit, the path is on registry `Software\\PostgreSQL\\Installations\\postgresql-8.4\\`.  Would anybody tell where is it?

Comment: Win 7 stores it at `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.4`

Comment: I want to check isPostgresql installed on windows xp 64 bit, if i check from program file when postgre has been uninstall the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.4 is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Registry settings of 32 bit binaries on Windows 64 bit systems are found in the Wow6432Node subfolder of Software, so:

```
\Software\Wow6432Node\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-8.4\
```